# Iterating Meteor cursor with #each gives error

Tags: templates, meteor, each

I have the following code and am getting

> {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values

HTML:

```html
<template name='subscribers'>
  {{#each stat in getPythonStats "WNScan"}}
  <div>
    {{stat.name}}: {{stat.value}}
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Javascript:

```js
Template.subscribers.helpers({
  getPythonStats(server) {
    var status = WNstatus.find({'server': server});
    if (!status)
      status = [{'status': 'shutdown'}, {'count': 0}, {'startTime': 'Never'}, {'runTime': 0}];
    console.log(status);
    return status;
  }
});
```

Console output:

```
{_id: M…D.ObjectID, server: "WNScan", status: "shutdown", startTime: "2017-10-10 22:40:12", runTime: 5.39, …}
```

Looks like a cursor to me. I thought at first the problem was with the argument to `getPythonStats` confusing `#each`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem since the helper is being called. I've tried both `collection.find` and `collection.findOne` (which return identical results since there is never more than one document that satisfies the query), with the same result. I have almost identical code elsewhere that uses `{{with getPythonStats "WNScan"}}` and that works fine. Also, if the `"WNScan"` document isn't found, the returned array produces the same error. This is with the latest 1.5 version of Meteor.

Comment: Console output does _not_ look like cursor, it looks like one document. Of course, `{{#each}}` won't iterate over it. Please, add code to clarify `WNstatus` — what is it?

Comment: `WNStatus` is a collection schema name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you want to iterate over each key in `status` but **#each needs an array or a cursor** and `status` isn't!

`collection.find` returns a cursor, `collection.findOne` returns a document (not an array of documents).

The equivalent of `collection.findOne` using `collection.find` is `collection.find().fetch()[0]`

Javascript:

```js
const defaultStatus = {
  status: 'shutdown',
  count: 0,
  startTime: 'Never',
  runTime: 0
};
Template.subscribers.helpers({
    getPythonStats(server) {
        const status = WNstatus.findOne({ 'server': server});
        console.log(status);
        return _.pairs(status || defaultStatus);
    }
});
```

HTML

```html
<template name='subscribers'>
    {{#each stat in getPythonStats "WNScan"}}
    <div>
       <!-- stat is now an array containing key and value -->
       {{stat.[0]}}: {{stat.[1]}}
    </div>
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

[`_.pairs()` documentation](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/1.5.2/#pairs)

Comment: Perfect. Works great once I shift the `ID` and `server` elements out of the array. I didn't know about `_.pair`. And thanks for clearly explaining the difference between `find` and `findOne` (and how to make `find` work like `findOne`. I'm still learning this stuff on my own.